# Dropdown css/javascript boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've found some solutions for custom drawn dropdown boxes to replace the HTML select element, namely the jquery-image-dropdown solution.

However, how can I get a box which requires a click to open, and overdraws the selected item at the top, as at: http://www.xero.com/

Sorry if that's a bit confusing, essentially I'm looking for a solution similar to that.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it from stratch, it's not to complex.

Sample:

```
<html>
    <script>
        function ShowList()
        {
            document.getElementById("List").style.display = "block";                
            document.getElementById("ChangeLocation").style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
<body>
    <span id="ChangeLocation" onclick="javascript:ShowList();">Change location</span>
    <ul id="List" style="display:none">
        <li>Global</li>
        <li>United Kingdom</li>
        <li>Australia</li>
    <ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick check of the page's source reveals that the site uses the [jQuery clickMenu plugin](http://p.sohei.org/jquery-plugins/clickmenu/). Have you looked into that?